# What is the English name of the result known as the "Shared-Edge Theorem" in Chinese?

Tags: geometry, triangles

There is this theorem that I think is pretty useful, but I don't know the English name. It's called 共边定理 in Chinese which literally means Shared-Edge Theorem. There is a Chinese Wikipedia article about it at https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%B1%E8%BE%B9%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86.

[image: Triangle PAB]
<sub>(source: [hudong.com](http://a3.att.hudong.com/72/81/01200000024129134400812943303_s.jpg))</sub>

The theorem says that following for this triangle:

$$\frac{\triangle PAB}{\triangle QAB}=\frac{PM}{QM}$$
I need to know the English name for this so I can reference it on my tests. As you can see, this works because a side is shared.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it has  a name in English.

Comment: In Spanish this has no name.

Comment: This is sometimes referred to as ["The Area Principle"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AreaPrinciple.html). Grünbaum and Shepard   (1995) used it as a unifying notion in proofs of Ceva's Theorem and Menelaus' Theorem (and others).

Comment: This is called the Area Principle. Having said that, if it's not named, then anybody can stake claim to it.

Comment: In [*Mechanical Theorem Proving in Geometry*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274052351_Mechanical_Theorem_Proving_in_Geometry) in TELEKOMNIKA, 共邊定理 is referred as "Public Edge Theorem (1970, Zhang)".  "Zhang" refers to Zhang Jing-zhong (張景中).  IMHO, "Common Edge Theorem" would be a translation that sounds more natural in English while retaining the Chinese literal meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand upon my comment, here's an excerpt from Grünbaum and Shephard's 1995 article ["Ceva, Menelaus, and the Area Principle" (JSTOR link)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690569) in *Mathematics Magazine*.

> The purpose of this note is to show that [the theorems of Ceva, Menelaus, and Hoehn] and other results, and their extensions to general polygons with arbitrarily many sides, are the consequences of a simple idea **which we shall call** the *area principle*. [Description of equality between ratios of segments and associated areas, essentially matching OP's description of the Shared-Edge Theorem.]

**Emphasis** mine. Grünbaum and Shephard appear to have coined this name for the result. I'm not sure how widely-known the name is.

The article is quite interesting, by the way. The authors have always had a real knack for generalizing things in unexpected ---and unexpectedly-broad--- ways.

Answer (score 1):

Also called the "area method" in addition to "area principle" -- to the extent that such minor distinctions matter -- according to Shephard's 1999 "Euler's Triangle Theorem" that cites the 1995 Grünbaum & Shephard paper mentioned above.  [1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.193.7328)